# Why Monaco editor's suggestionHelper opens after every 2nd character key stroke?

Tags: editor, monaco-editor, visual-studio-monaco

I was trying to implement my custom completion item provider for monaco-editor and I was expecting that completionItemProvider will be invoked for every keystroke. Instead, it is getting triggered after every 2nd character.

```js
function createDependencyProposals(range) {
    // returning a static list of proposals, not even looking at the prefix (filtering is done by the Monaco editor),
    // here you could do a server side lookup
    return [
        {
            label: '"lodash"',
            kind: monaco.languages.CompletionItemKind.Function,
            documentation: "The Lodash library exported as Node.js modules.",
            insertText: '"lodash": "*"',
            range: range
        },
        {
            label: '"express"',
            kind: monaco.languages.CompletionItemKind.Function,
            documentation: "Fast, unopinionated, minimalist web framework",
            insertText: '"express": "*"',
            range: range
        },
        {
            label: '"mkdirp"',
            kind: monaco.languages.CompletionItemKind.Function,
            documentation: "Recursively mkdir, like <code>mkdir -p</code>",
            insertText: '"mkdirp": "*"',
            range: range
        },
        {
            label: '"my-third-party-library"',
            kind: monaco.languages.CompletionItemKind.Function,
            documentation: "Describe your library here",
            insertText: '"${1:my-third-party-library}": "${2:1.2.3}"',
            insertTextRules: monaco.languages.CompletionItemInsertTextRule.InsertAsSnippet,
            range: range
        }
    ];
}


monaco.languages.registerCompletionItemProvider('json', {
    provideCompletionItems: function(model, position) {
        // find out if we are completing a property in the 'dependencies' object.
        var textUntilPosition = model.getValueInRange({startLineNumber: 1, startColumn: 1, endLineNumber: position.lineNumber, endColumn: position.column});
        console.log(textUntilPosition);
        var match = textUntilPosition.match(/"dependencies"\s*:\s*\{\s*("[^"]*"\s*:\s*"[^"]*"\s*,\s*)*([^"]*)?$/);
        if (!match) {
            return { suggestions: [] };
        }
        var word = model.getWordUntilPosition(position);
        var range = {
            startLineNumber: position.lineNumber,
            endLineNumber: position.lineNumber,
            startColumn: word.startColumn,
            endColumn: word.endColumn
        };
        return {
            suggestions: createDependencyProposals(range)
        };
    }
});

monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById("container"), {
    value: "{\n\t\"dependencies\": {\n\t\t\n\t}\n}\n",
    language: "json"
});
```

I checked this code in [monaco playground](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html) and when I typed some gibberish very fast. The console log showed me this

[image]

Is there any configuration with which I can make completionItemProvider trigger on every keystroke? Or any explanation regarding this behaviour will help.

Thanks in advance!